# Turning a list into sublist of a given size

Tags: dart

I have a list of X widgets and want to show them in a ListView of Rows. I know that I can fit N widget in each Row.

I want to do:

```
  var MyListOfRows = ListView(
    children: intoSublists(widgetList,subListSize).map(
        (sublist)=> Row(
          children: sublist,
        )
    ).toList()
  );
```

I thought about implementing intoSublists with complex modulo magic but that seems to leave complicated code and I'm hoping that there's a easy way to implement this is dart. Is there?

(This is part of a component that I pass a minimum height and width together with a list of Widgets. The component is supposed to display the Widgets as big as possible and if there are too many Widgets because of the minimum dimensions display a scrollable list)

Comment: How do you know you can fit N widgets into a single row? Do they have a dynamic width that guarantees they will all fit without overflowing? Is this true for every device this app could possibly run on?

Comment: @Abion47 : The N gets calculated beforehand based on available space.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel. Instead of a `ListView` and a bunch of `Row`s, use a `SingleChildScrollView` and a [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html), and let the `Wrap` determine how many widgets can fit in a particular "row" based on the actual size of the screen.

```dart
var myList = SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Wrap(
    children: widgetList,
  ),
);
```

EDIT: If you want the widgets to stretch to fill the row (and all the widgets are going to be the same size), you can also use a [`GridView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html):

```dart
var myGrid = GridView(
  crossAxisCount: subListSize, // How many widgets you want to be across
  children: widgetList,
);
```

Comment: As far as I understand Wrap doesn't interact with Expanded() in the way Row interacts with it and as such this will produce a different result.

Comment: @Christian You didn't mention `Expanded` in your question. What _is_ the intended result?

Comment: This is part of a component that I pass a minimum height and width together with a list of Widgets. The component is supposed to display the Widgets as big as possible and if there are too many Widgets because of the minimum dimensions display a scrollable list.

Comment: @Christian Is each widget the same size?

Comment: Yes, they are all of the same size.

Comment: @Christian Then it sounds like you want a [`GridView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) instead.